# Where is/was village of Chalewisz in 1913 Russia?

Tags: russia, historical-gazetteer, 1910s

My husband's father was born in 1896 in the then Russian Empire. He came to the US in 1913 on the ship Caronia. On the copy we have of the ship's manifest, it states he came from chalewisz.  However, on his later filled alien registration form, he states he was born in or near " Halvedi (city) Cherneoska (province), Russia.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Can you edit your question to include images of the relevant extracts of the the documents?